# how to use try and except in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, logic

I am trying to get the user_id from the sqlite3 database in python and store in in an array. This is what I have tried:

```
LIST_ARRAY=[]
def start(bot, update):
    value = update.message.from_user.id
    print("VALUE first: ", value)
    try:
        for row in connection.execute("SELECT *from userdetails WHERE user_id=?", (value,)):
            print(row)
            user_id, full_name, address, phone_number, email = row
            data = [user_id]
            LIST_ARRAY[0] = data[0]
    except:
        print(LIST_OF_ADMINS)
```

It doesn't get the value please help me to sort this out.

My data variable doesn't get added in the list array

Comment: Perhaps start by looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try)

Comment: First note that a `list` and an `array` is different. You are using array notation to add the data to a list. use `LIST_ARRAY.append(data[0])`

Comment: Is the spacing like that in your program? That would cause a problem. You need the "try" and "except" lined up as well as having the print through LIST_ARRAY statements indented the same under the "for", and having the "print" under the "except" indented the same as the stuff under the "try"

Comment: _"it doesn't get the value"_. So, what _is_ it doing? If your answer is anything but "it crashes with an IndendationError", please [edit] your post so the indentation matches what's in your actual code.

Comment: Get rid of the `try/except` and then see what the error is. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: If a line of code can't produce the exception you are trying to catch, it probably doesn't belong in the `try` block. And `except` should *always* take an exception: `Exception` at the very least, to avoid catching things like `SystemExit`, but the more focused, the better.

Comment: @Kevin it has the same indentations as it have in my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cant help you with the database issue but i can answer the question of "How to use try and except in python"

Try and Except are used in python to handle errors when they occur in your code as shown below

```
x=[0,'It Worked',2]

try:
    print(x[4])
except IndexError:
    print("Oh No there was an error")

try:
    print(x[1])
except IndexError:
    print("Oh No there was an error")
```

so in the example i made above i created an array with 2 ints and a string... I then "TRY" to print the contents in x[4] which do not exist which results in a IndexError... because i told the program to print(x[4]) and the error that i prepared for occurred the "EXCEPT" statement is executed and the code beneath it is also executed

the output of the code is:

```
'Oh No there was an error'
'It Worked'
```

Comment: Itmdid it the same way